# cocos2d multi-touch and CCMotionStreak

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to use multitouch in my app....but I have to display a streak when the finger move on the screen... but I see only ONE streak, instead of TWO! how can I create and move 2 streaks together??

Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    for (int n=0; n < [allTouches count]; n++)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:n];
        CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];

        streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:0.3 minSeg:20 width:13 color:[CCColor colorWithUIColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] textureFilename:@"scia.png"];
       [streak setPosition:touchLoc];
       [self addChild:streak z:30];
    }
 }

 -(void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    for (int n=0; n < [allTouches count]; n++)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:n];
        CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];

            [streak setPosition:touchLoc];
            [self detectObjects:touchLoc];
    }
 }
```

Comment: i see you have only one 'sreak' object , so you are applying the changes always to that object ... with the last touch in the array. You probably want a set of streaks, one for each touch, and find a way of associating a touch to the appropriate streak, so you can recover the streak in touchMoved (possibly the userObject property of the streak could be the touch in question).

Comment: exact, I'm doing different test but I don't find how to associate the touch to that specific streak...

Comment: I have not used myself, but every CCNode , hence CCMotionStreak has a userObject property. You could set that to the touch associated to the streak. In touch moved, for each touch go through your streaks until you find the one where streak.userObject == theTouch; , then move that streak's position to the touch.  Something like that. ymmv :)

Answer (score 0):

for multitouch inside CCLayer you can use multitouch by CCStandardTouchDelegate function.
build in cocos2d
if you are looking for Fruit Ninja Blade effect.. use `CCBlade` instead of `CCMotionStreak`
https://github.com/hiepnd/CCBlade

```
/// .h File
CFMutableDictionaryRef map;

// .m File
void releaseStreak(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value)
{
    [(CCMotionStreak*)value removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
CFDictionaryValueCallBacks valueCallbacks = {
   0,
   NULL,
   releaseStreak,
   NULL,
   NULL
};

-(id) init
{
   if( (self=[super init])) {
     isTouchEnabled_ = 1;
     [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
     map = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,0,NULL,&valueCallbacks);
   }
}

- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{ 
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
       CCMotionStreak *streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:0.3 minSeg:20 width:13 color:[CCColor colorWithUIColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] textureFilename:@"scia.png"];
        CFDictionaryAddValue(map,touch,streak);
        CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        pos = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:pos];
       [streak setPosition: pos];
       [self addChild:streak z:30];
    }
 }

- (void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
 {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
            CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
            pos = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:pos];
            CCMotionStreak *_streak = (CCMotionStreak *)CFDictionaryGetValue(map, touch);
            [streak setPosition:pos];
            [self detectObjects:pos];
    }
 }
- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CCMotionStreak *_streak = (CCMotionStreak *)CFDictionaryGetValue(map, touch);
        CFDictionaryRemoveValue(map,touch);
        //i already added removeFromParent above no need to add release code.
    }
}
```

let me know if the above code work for you.

Comment: My initial idea was just to use CCBLade but is not compatible with cocos2d v3!

Comment: @swifferina : ok i haven't tried the above code in cocos2d v3 ..
is the above answer is working ?